# Azure Function - Queue Trigger - confusion over library being used (C#)

Tags: azure, function, queue, servicebus

I've created a simple Azure function which is triggered on a service bus queue.

I'd like to inject a the full message payload into the trigger. Now there are 2 libraries available for working with Azure Service Bus - the older https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/ and the newer https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/

If I inject in the message payload using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message works, however using the newer Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessage gives a run-time error.

Ideally would like to use the newer library - is there any config change required to make this work?

The error is

Executed 'IncomingMessageProcessingFunction' (Failed, Id=01b3f0c1-fe4d-4d0f-89db-7814a4a0ddbe, Duration=2756ms)
[2021-09-13T10:56:47.944Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: IncomingMessageProcessingFunction. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myQueueItem'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'ServiceBusMessage') uses Json.NET serialization or XML object serialization.
[2021-09-13T10:56:47.946Z]  1. If ContentType is 'application/json' deserialize as JSON
[2021-09-13T10:56:47.948Z]  2. If ContentType is not 'application/json' attempt to deserialize using Message.GetBody, which will handle cases like XML object serialization
[2021-09-13T10:56:47.949Z]  3. If this deserialization fails, do a final attempt at JSON deserialization to catch cases where the content type might be incorrect
[2021-09-13T10:56:47.951Z] The JSON parser failed: Error converting value 123 to type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessage'. Path '', line 1, position 3.

Works

```
 [FunctionName("IncomingMessageProcessingFunction")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("incomingmessageprocessingqueue", Connection = "SERVICEBUS")]Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem.Body}");
```

Comment: Please include the run-time error you are getting.

Comment: Added above details of error above

Comment: what's in SERVICEBUS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems json error
Try using System.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft
Or maybe the payload is not correct